# Function giving unexpected result

Tags: python, function

Could anyone explain why this function gives "None" at the end?

```
def displayHand(hand):
    """
    Displays the letters currently in the hand.

    For example:
    >>> displayHand({'a':1, 'x':2, 'l':3, 'e':1})
    Should print out something like:
       a x x l l l e
    The order of the letters is unimportant.

    hand: dictionary (string -> int)
    """
    for letter in hand.keys():
        for j in range(hand[letter]):
             print(letter,end=" ")       # print all on the same line
    print()                             # print an empty line
```

Comment: There's an implicit `return None` at the end of every function, so if you don't return anything, it will return `None`

Comment: Where does it give None? You aren't calling the function in this code.

Answer (score 2):

The function is returning None because there is no other explicit return value; If a function has no return statement, the default is None.

Comment: It does return what it should when called print(displayhand({'a':1, 'x':2, 'l':3, 'e':1}), which is  "a x x l l l e" but adds None in the second line.

Answer (score 1):

If a function doesn't return anything, then it automatically returns `None`.